# Get newest data after submit data without page reload using vue script setup + axios

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, vue-composition-api, vue-script-setup

Please kindly help me with this, because I'm new in vue.js.

So, I have 2 Vue files **:**

1. `Greetinglist.vue`, It calls data from api using axios.get
2. `Greeting.vue`, It posts data using axios.post

After submit data, how to refresh the data without reload the page ?
I'm using `<script setup>` tag.

(greetinglist.vue)

```
 <div class="p-2" v-for="(message, index) in messages" :key="index">
   <div>
      <h3>{{ message.name }}<span>{{message.date}}</span></h3>
      <p class="text-slate-300 text-lg">{{ message.greeting }}</p>
      </div>
    <hr/>
 </div>

<script setup>
import {ref, onMounted } from 'vue'
import axios from 'axios'

let messages = ref([]);

function getMessages() {
    axios.get('http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/messages')
    .then((result) => {
        messages.value = result.data
    }).catch((err) => {
        console.log(err.response.data)
    })
}

onMounted(() => {
    getMessages()
});
</script>
```

(Greeting.vue)

```
<form @submit.prevent="store()">
  <div class="">
     <input type="text" placeholder="" v-model="messages.name">
     <textarea name="" id="" cols="28" rows="10" placeholder="" v-model="messages.greeting"></textarea>
  </div>
  <button>Submit</button>
</form>
 <div>
   <GreetingList/>
 </div>

<script setup>
import { reactive } from 'vue'
import axios from 'axios'
import GreetingList from './GreetingList.vue'

const messages = reactive({
    name: '',
    greeting: '',
});

function store() {
    axios.post('http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/messages', messages)
    .then((result) => {
        
        messages.name = ''
        messages.greeting = ''
    })
    .catch((err) => {
    })
}
</script>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, please share your code rather than images of code, see how do I ask a good question [ask].

Answer (score 0):

You can move getMessages function to greeting.vue, and change greetinglist.vue to use props

greeting.vue

```
<form @submit.prevent="store()">
  <div class="">
     <input type="text" placeholder="" v-model="messages.name">
     <textarea name="" id="" cols="28" rows="10" placeholder="" v-model="messages.greeting"></textarea>
  </div>
  <button>Submit</button>
</form>
 <div>
   <GreetingList :messages="messageList" />
 </div>

<script setup>
import { reactive } from 'vue'
import axios from 'axios'
import GreetingList from './GreetingList.vue'

const messages = reactive({
    name: '',
    greeting: '',
});
let messageList = ref([])

function store() {
    axios.post('http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/messages', messages)
    .then((result) => {
        
        messages.name = ''
        messages.greeting = ''

        getMessages()
    })
    .catch((err) => {
    })
}

function getMessages() {
    axios.get('http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/messages')
    .then((result) => {
        messageList.value = result.data
    }).catch((err) => {
        console.log(err.response.data)
    })
}

onMounted(() => {
    getMessages()
});
</script>
```

greetinglist.vue

```
<script setup>
  defineProps(['messages'])
</script>
```

Comment: thx. but still i have to reload the page to refresh the greetinglist. is it okay just to call getMessage() inside the function store?

Comment: yes, you need to call getMessages() inside the function store. sorry I missed that part. solution edited.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your requirement correctly, I am assuming you have both the components in a single page and you want to get the details of newly added greeting from `Greeting.vue` in the `GreetingList.vue` reactively (without refreshing the route). If Yes, You can achieve that by calling a getMessages() method on successfully promise of `axios.post` and then pass the results in the `GreetingList.vue`.

Demo (I just created it using Vue 2, You can change it accordingly as per Vue 3) **:**

```js
Vue.component('child', {
  // declare the props
  props: ['msglist'],
  // just like data, the prop can be used inside templates
  // and is also made available in the vm as this.message
  template: `<div>
              <div v-for="(message, index) in msglist" :key="index">
                <h3>{{ message.name }}</h3>
                <p>{{ message.greeting }}</p>
                <hr/>
              </div>
             </div>`
});

var app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    messages: {
      name: null,
      greeting: null
    },
    // For demo, I am just mock data for initial greeting listing.
    messageList: [{
        name: 'Alpha',
        greeting: 'Hi !'
      }, {
        name: 'Beta',
        greeting: 'Hello !'      
      }]
  },
  methods: {
    store() {
        // Post API call will happen here.
      // on success, make a call to get list of greetings.
      if (this.messages.name && this.messages.greeting) {
        this.getMessages();
      }
    },
    getMessages() {
        // Get API call will happen here. For demo, I am just using the mock data and pushing the newly submitted greeting in a exisiting messageList.
      this.messageList.push({
        name: this.messages.name,
        greeting: this.messages.greeting
      })
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <input type="text" placeholder="Name" v-model="messages.name"/>
     <textarea cols="28" rows="10" placeholder="Greeting" v-model="messages.greeting"></textarea>
     <button @click="store">Submit</button>
  <child :msglist="messageList">
  </child>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<template>
  <div>
    <h1>Post component</h1>
    <form @submit="submitData" method="post">
      <input type="text" placeholder="Enter Title" name="tilte" v-model="userdata.title" /><br />
      <br />
      <input type="text" placeholder="Enter Author" name="author" v-model="userdata.author" /><br /><br />
      <button type="submit">Submit Data</button>
    </form>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import axios from "axios";

export default {
  name: "postcomponent",
  data() {
    return {
      userdata: {
        title: null,
        author: null,
      },
    };
  },
  methods: {
    submitData(e) {
      axios.post(
        "http://localhost:3000/posts",
        this.userdata
      ).then((result) => {
        console.warn(result)
      });
      e.preventDefault();
    },
  },
};
</script>
```